# Obtaining exotic matter (formula) in the process of computer simulation

Tags: standard-model, exotic-matter

It is theoretically be possible to obtain exotic matter on the basis of ordinary matter?

Assume that we have infinite computational resources.

Is there a way to simulate the process of obtaining exotic matter?

Probably we need some observation - where it take?

Such computer modeling of exotic matter is possible?

What can we do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it could be done with infinite computing resources. Calculating the energy levels and the wavefunctions of quantummechanical systems, it isn't even an exponential problem, only polinomyal. The problem is that the complexity of these calculations goes mostly with a high power of the required precision.

For example, calculating the mass of the proton was essentially an integration problem of all possible paths in a space of many millions of dimensions. Yes, it can be calculated in theory, but it is practically impossible in practice. The people finally did it, had to use a big GPU-accelerated computing cluster, and use a lot of simplifications. But finally they succeed. And it was only a proton, i.e. 3 quarks and the gluon soup around them. More complex systems (many protons, or like the chemical properties of the sulphuric acid) is currently impossible without significant simplifications, even with highly developed computing technology.

Comment: Thank you very much for help. Perhaps you know of any examples of software that can be theoretically used for this purpose?

Comment: @Aurelio Unfortunately, no. As far I know, physicists use mainly mathematical software, like Derive, Matlab, Mathematica, extended with addons for physical computing, for desktop calculations. For big computing problems, parallel frameworks are the most popular, and they are programmed in fortran or in c.